# How Can I use 2 different event box sizes

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to use event boxes with 2 diferent sizes?
I have 2 calendar sources, and I would like to use "height:2em" for the first calendar events, and "height:1em" for the second calendar events.
Is it possible?

Thanxs in Advance...

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, could you make us a sketch of how you would like the events to look or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Event Object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) has a className property.

For instance, if I had the following CSS classes

```
.firstClass {
   height: 2em;
}
.secondClass {
   height: 1em;
}
```

and the following Event Objects

```
      // First Source
      {
        title: 'First Source',
        start: new Date(2012, 0, 1),
        className: 'firstClass'
      }

      // Second Source
      {
        title: 'Second Source',
        start: new Date(2012, 0, 2),
        className: 'secondClass'
      }
```

I'd get a result like this

[image: FullCalendar]

Comment: @user1144461, no problem. If it resolved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark off to the left.

Comment: @Brandon i dont know if this is the right place to ask but can i use the same way to alter the width of the event. I tried to use this but it didn't work. I want to conditionally change the width of the event markers.

Comment: @khizar, no, this method won't work for width. There is another way, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389552/how-to-edit-width-of-event-in-fullcalendar