# Edit width of event in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

i know this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389552/how-to-edit-width-of-event-in-fullcalendar) but i am stuck with this problem and have already wasted a day so i thought making a new question might help with a quick response.. I am using full calendar in a web app, and i wanted to change the width of the events conditionally. For some i want the width halved and for some quartered. This is the solution proposed there

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
         $(element).css('width','50px');
      }
});
```

Now i how can i use this to halve the with that is already set? If i inspect an element i see that the absolut width is set but i think it is going to change depending on the screen size and calendar size, so can i somehow do something like `width : width/2` so that it does not break on a resize. if its a very simple question, please bear with me as i am very new to web development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign class names to the events that you want to resize.

Then in the `eventAfterRender` method you can do something like this:

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {  
     var width = $(element).width();

     // Check which class the event has so you know whether it's half or quarter width
     if($(element).hasClass("HalfClass"))
        width = width / 2;
     if($(element).hasClass("QuarterClass"))
        width = width / 4;

     // Set the new width
     $(element).css('width', width + 'px');
  },
```

Comment: @Brandon as your code for width will work but how to calculate left alignment of element after width given ?