# FullCalendar - customize event label

Tags: fullcalendar

**Intro:**

Primefaces *p:schedule* uses FullCalendar, so I must ask if FullCalendar can do what I need. If FullCalendar cannot then I will know that Primefaces cannot either.

**Question:** *(short to be clear)*

Is there any way to customize event label?
I would like to have label (without hour) with three lines, for example:

Negiotiations
**Scott Tiger**
level: *hard*

As you see second line is bold, and in third line we have italic text. Is possible to achieve something like this out of the box? If not any sugestions how to do that?

Comment: Hey downvoter, I know you didn't know an answer and reason to downvote (at least you cannot write), but anyway happy new year :P

Comment: Actually its possible through Jquery and javascript and you don´t need to alter any source code. The reason for downvoting is because there are many questions regarding this issue that might be usefull for your problem, many of them are not conclusive but might give you an idea on how to do things. For example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444711/fullcalendar-change-event-appointment-diary-entry-height)...

Downvoting is not to hurt your feelings, is to enhance quality in S.O.

Happy new year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking source code (version 1.6.4) the answer is:

**This is not possible**

In order to achieve this, source code has to be modified.

Answer (score 2):

An old post, but my question was the same.

Now with FullCalendar version 2.7.3 you can modify event label with **eventRender** attribut.

See the example :

```
var calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar(
{
//...
eventRender: function(event, element) {
                console.log(event);
                console.log(element);
                element.text("a bigger text for this object, you can modify element as you want now with another label");
            },
//...
}
```

I hope my answer will help.