# Fullcalendar scheduler resize row height

Tags: fullcalendar, scheduler

I'm using Fullcalendar with the scheduler add-on and I want to reduce the events height and also the row height of the different resources. Anyone an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I had encountered this problem and used this

1. Define a class name in ur .css file

```css
.fc-resized-row { height: 24px !important; }
```

2. Extend on the fullcalendar scheduler eventRender event

```js
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
      $(".fc-rows table tbody tr .fc-widget-content div").addClass('fc-resized-row');
      $(".fc-content table tbody tr .fc-widget-content div").addClass('fc-resized-row');
      $(".fc-body .fc-resource-area .fc-cell-content").css('padding', '0px');
      },
```

Hope this might help anyone who encounters this issue.

Cheers!

Comment: It might be a better idea to use the `eventAfterAllRender` trigger instead of `eventRender`, since `eventRender` is called on each single event in the view and the given code needs to be called only once after everything is rendered (which `eventAfterAllRender` would be perfectly suited for).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the height of each time slot rows, you can override the css class.

```
.fc-agenda-slots td div {
     height: 40px !important;
}
```

or (for my agenda without sheduler)

```
.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td {
         height: 1.0em; .. }
```

You can find it in fifth line of fullcalendar css

For the event height : 
[FullCalendar - Change event (appointment, diary entry) height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444711/fullcalendar-change-event-appointment-diary-entry-height)

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but after rendering the cal no class fc-agenda-slots or fc-time-grid is present...

Comment: 'no class fc-agenda-slots or fc-time-grid is present' —indeed.